# Create columns from tagged words

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector with tagged words like `c(#142#856#856.2#745, NA, #856#855, NA, #685, #663, #965.23, #855#658#744#122)`.

Words are separated by sharp. I would like create a data frame with one column for each different code, and then write 1 or 0 (or NA) depending if that code it is in that row or not.

The idea is that each element becomes a row, and each code becomes a column, and then if the code is in that element then in the column is marked with 1, or 0 if that code is not in that element.

```
ID | 142 | 856 |856.2 | ... | 122 |
1  |  1  |  1  |  1   | ... |  0  |
2  |  0  |  0  |  0   | ... |  0  |
...
```

I know how to do this with a complex algorithm plenty of loops. But, is it there any easy way to do this in a easy way?

Comment: Can you explain this part: `depending if that code it is in that row or not`?What row? Where `ID` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this fairly easily using `stringr`:

```
# First we load the package
library(stringr)
# Then we create your example data vector
tagged_vector <- c('#142#856#856.2#745', NA, '#856#855', NA, '#685', '#663',
                   '#965.23', '#855#658#744#122')
# Next we need to get all the unique codes
# stringr's str_extract_all() can do this:
all_codes <- str_extract_all(string=tagged_vector, pattern='(?<=#)[0-9\\.]+')
# We just looked for one or more numbers and/or dots following a '#' character
# Now we just want the unique ones:
unique_codes <- unique(na.omit(unlist(all_codes)))
# Then we can use grepl() to check whether each code occurs in any element
# I've also used as.numeric() since you want 0/1 instead of TRUE/FALSE
result <- data.frame(sapply(unique_codes, function(x){
    as.numeric(grepl(x, tagged_vector))
}))
# Then we add in your ID column and move it to the front:
result$ID <- 1:nrow(result)
result <- result[ , c(ncol(result), 1:(ncol(result)-1))]
```

The result is

```
  ID X142 X856 X856.2 X745 X855 X685 X663 X965.23 X658 X744 X122
1  1    1    1      1    1    0    0    0       0    0    0    0
2  2    0    0      0    0    0    0    0       0    0    0    0
3  3    0    1      0    0    1    0    0       0    0    0    0
4  4    0    0      0    0    0    0    0       0    0    0    0
5  5    0    0      0    0    0    1    0       0    0    0    0
6  6    0    0      0    0    0    0    1       0    0    0    0
7  7    0    0      0    0    0    0    0       1    0    0    0
8  8    0    0      0    0    1    0    0       0    1    1    1
```

You may notice in the column names an "X" precedes each code. That's because in R [a variable name may not begin with a number](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f).

Comment: Thanks, Is exactly this. I just change the description to make it more clear.

Comment: Glad this helped.